# how to perform the action when clicking the html submit button without using runat server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

how to perform an action when i click the html submit button without using runat server. Where i have to write the code and what i have to write. Please help me. I have a below code:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter User Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtUserId" name="userId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkRememberMe" />
                <label for="chkRememberMe">Remember Me</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="Submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Login" name="submitButton"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to write logic in *aspx.cs file. Thank you.

Comment: why you do not want to use runat server for button?? also which framework of asp.net you are using for your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any http post of a page back to the server will trigger your codebehind to be executed, regardless of whether you have a runat="server" or not. You can detect this by inspecting the IsPostback property of the Page object.

All asp.net buttons are "submit" buttons. Typically, you'll want to have a runat="server" attribute on your button so you can handle events for that specific button in your codebehind. While I can only think of a few select reasons for not, the primary one typically cited is that the runat="server" causes the control ID to be changed so that it is unpredictable in client scripts and CSS. If this is your reason, you can set the clientidmode to static on that control.

Comment: Thank you Bernesto for giving response. Your Explained very well. I agree with you. So, finally I will use asp.net server button control. That's ok. Just one thing i want to know is i could not understand the last 2 lines of 2nd paragraph from your explanation. Can you please give some brief information about those lines.. Thank you